# Telethon client exits my function, does not execute the rest of it

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

```
def legit():
     msg = scam_msgs.pop(0)
     alert = client.send_message(entity=msg['channel'],message=random.choice(scam_alert), reply_to = msg['msg_id'])
     print('test1')
     data = {'msg' : msg['msg_id'], 'alert' : alert.id}
     print('test2')
     reply_msgs.append(data)
```

The above code is a function I made for replying to scammers in an orphaned Telegram group (to help me learn python). I am using the Telethon library. I found the scammers delete their advert when I reply to it stating it is a scam, so I wanted to log the details of their original message and catch the deletion of the original message, and subsequently delete my reply to it.

I found it was not logging the alert.id and through some very basic debugging found that after it sends the message to the group, the function must be exiting. The message goes to the channel, but "test1" is not printed, or 'test2' for that matter.

There are no errors printed to the screen for this function terminating like this.

I've tried to look through the docs and googled, but I can't find any thing which tells me I must be missing something simple and fundamental. Is any one able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Okay, I have had this running for some time now, and its triggered quite a few times and is doing a great job. But just then, its printed 'test1'. Only the once, and its back to not printing it. I think its got to do with async? main in async. Will unexcuted code get cleaned up if it isnt executed in time?

Comment: Make sure to [configure Python's `logging` if you haven't already](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/basic/updates.html). It will log unhandled exceptions. The only way a function can "exit" early is either using an early `return` or an error being raised (barring other hacks which are likely not in place here). So make sure you're not swallowing errors.